# Azure Security Benchmark parameters file

Tags: json, azure, azure-policy

I am trying to use a json file with parameters when assigning the Azure Security Benchmark policy via CLI:

az policy assignment create `

```
--name "Name" `
--display-name "Name" `
--scope /providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/MyMG `
--policy-set-definition ASBID `
--params ".\my.parameters.json"
```

So the parameters file contains the settings for each individual policy within the initiative and will set it as AuditIfNotExist, Audit, Disabled. However I can't seem to get the parameters file correct. How should the json file be written?